# Validate HUGE xml in browser side using JS

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd, web-worker, progressive-web-apps

I need to validate a really huge XML (2GB) file in browser (In a PWA app using Web Workers). First the file must be validated with the XSD schema and then it must be transformed to JSON objects.

I just tried reading the file with the FileReader and slices, I can read the file, but I can't validate it.

I first tried thing like the following (it works with small files (KB to some MB)):

```
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content, "text/xml");            
        if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length > 0) {
            isValid = false;
        }
```

Then I use FileReader, this is working OK:

```
    var r = new FileReader();
    var blob = _file.slice(_offset, length + _offset);
    r.onload = readEventHandler;
    r.readAsText(blob);
```

But now I don't know how to validate the BIG xml using these slices.

Is there any lib or built-in JS function in order to achieve it (Using vanilla JS preferably)? Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Yeah I'm also interested. So this is a file that the user loads from their file system?

Comment: Have you tried SAX or Stream based XML parsers? You can process XML withour preloading whole file to memory, it's nothing new and it was used since XML was born for this particular reason. Nevertheless, i guess you'll have to skip browser native XML/DOM facilities.

Comment: @ZbigniewZagórski is there any SAX or STAX solution for javascript (browser client side)?? I can't find any that works well

Comment: LMGIFY - https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js, https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js ... Looks like none of them can do XSLT or validation but second advertises that it can have some pattern matching, so you don't have to track state manually.

Comment: @ZbigniewZagórski thanks, let me check it, last one explodes in Chrome

Answer (score 3):

We had a very similar requirement in our project and there was no suitable solution, so we came up with [xmlvalidate.js](https://github.com/openscd/xmlvalidate.js), a WASM compiled version of the schema validation functionality from `libxml2`.

This currently uses a string to communicate the XML to the web worker, but could easily be adapted to use a buffer instead (wasm uses a buffer internally anyway, this just means one less conversion) if you load the XML directly in the worker. Strings are currently limited to `1GiB` in Chrome and `512MiB` in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can validate an XML which is sliced based on length, where it wont be logically ending or connected to next one.

You can try to validate the whole xml version using [Web Workers](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/), to see if it helps. This will create a separate thread from your main process. So it will not interrupt your user interaction or other regular operations.

I'm not sure if your use case. But relying on client side for such bulky operation is not always reliable.. especially when the client device is of low end hardware / outdated browser with low performance. Validating at server side would be the reliable solution, which understandably comes at added cost of bandwidth and server side load.

Comment: I tried to validate the whole file, but browser explodes (Chrome and FF crashes* , the file is too BIG to handle, the memory is not enought (16GB PC), but the final users may have less or more memory and I can't manage that) .

Comment: Did you try using web-workers? That would've created a separate thread, which is the best bet you have for client side validation. If you cant manage the targeted devices, then only other option is to use server side validation, knowing its added cost.

Comment: as I said in the question "...(In a PWA app using Web Workers)...", the web worker dies with the big file :(

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I somehow got mislead to service worker. As I've mentioned, there is no guarantee this solution will work in app PCs even if it works in yours by having high end hardware. Only stable solution is to use server side validation.